Does a code being perfect have a specific effect on its automorphism group?
I know that the Perfect Binary Golay Code is very exceptional as it is the only perfect binary code that is not one of a few infinite families (Trivial, Simple Repitition, Hamming). The automorphism group of this Golay code is the Matthieu group $M_{23}$. $M_{23}$ is a sporadic simple group.
Is there any connection here, or is this a coincidince? The exceptional thing about the Golay code is it being unexpectedly perfect, and the exceptional thing about $M_{23}$ is it being unexpectedly simple.
When this Golay code is extended with a parity bit, the code is no longer simple, but the automorphism group ($M_{24}$) is still highly exceptional. What is the significance of adding the parity bit here, and why does it preserve this exceptionality that I am asking about?

Generally speaking what makes the non-sporadic simple groups non-sporadic is that they are the automorphism groups or nearly the automorphism groups of infinite families of familiar objects (e.g. projective spaces over finite fields). So, loosely speaking, when we can exhibit them as automorphism groups, the sporadic simple groups correspondingly arise as the automorphism groups or nearly the automorphism groups of exceptional objects that don't fit into infinite families (e.g. the Leech lattice), although I don't know that there's a precise theorem along these lines.
